# Filtro mysql por aproximação

Tags: mysql

me deparei com alguns casos em que usuários me relatavam não constar no banco de dados, certos clientes, notei que é comum a abreviação de nomes do meio ou a ausência deles, por exemplo:

Nome: João Ferreira da Silva

O usuário ao pesquisar:

```
select * from usuarios where nome like '%João da Silva%';
```

Não obteria resultado, bem como:

```
select * from usuarios where nome like '%João F. da Silva%';
```

Pergunto a vocês, qual a melhor forma para poder chegar a esses resultado de forma aproximada.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a documentação do MySQL, pode ser usado o `Full-text search`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Há várias formas de se usar, como por exemplo, pegando-se primeiro e último nome:

```sql
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE MATCH (nome)
    AGAINST ('+João +Silva' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Faz o replace dos espaços por `%` no termo de pesquisa antes que o utilizar na query. Assim apanhará nomes que existam pelo meio.

```sql
select * from usuarios where nome like '%João%da%Silva%';
```

Adimitindo o seu exemplo com o nome da base de dados registado como "João Ferreira da Silva", este caso server para termos de pesquisa como:

- João da Silva
- João F da Silva

Não servirá no entanto para `João F. da Silva`. Para apanhar este caso poderia também substituir o `.` por um `%`, ou remover o `.` por completo do termo de pesquisa, mas penso que poderá estar a entrar em casos muito específicos.

Comment: não é meio problemático trazer todo mundo com 'da' no nome?

Comment: Só trará todos os resultados com "da" se o termo de pesquisa for somente "da". No caso de ser "João da Silva" irá trazer apenas resultados que sejam do formado "*[qualquer coisa]* João *[qualquer coisa]* da *[qualquer coisa]* Silva *[qualquer coisa]*". O `%` funciona tipo *wildcard*.